# Split one column in many columns [Wordpress]

Tags: mysql, wordpress, split, multiple-columns

Good evening,

I want to help me with the split of a column in many columns, i tried many cases but not succeed...

> I have a table in which the entries are made in a column name ->
>   value:

[photo image sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M89lE.png)

> And I want to convert and to catch through from Query (Select):

[photo image sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPeTL.png)

I would be grateful if there is a solution...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query. (assuming [test] as your table name)

```
SELECT
 t.lead_id
 , t.form_id
-- sub-query for Value1
, (SELECT VALUE FROM test as inner_t WHERE inner_t.lead_id = t.lead_id and inner_t.form_id = t.form_id 
                                       and inner_t.field_number = 1) as value1
-- sub-query for Value2
, (SELECT VALUE FROM test as inner_t WHERE inner_t.lead_id = t.lead_id and inner_t.form_id = t.form_id 
                                       and inner_t.field_number = 2) as value2
-- sub-query for Value3
, (SELECT VALUE FROM test as inner_t WHERE inner_t.lead_id = t.lead_id and inner_t.form_id = t.form_id 
                                       and inner_t.field_number = 3) as value3
-- sub-query for Value4
, (SELECT VALUE FROM test as inner_t WHERE inner_t.lead_id = t.lead_id and inner_t.form_id = t.form_id 
                                       and inner_t.field_number = 4) as value4
FROM test AS t
GROUP BY lead_id, form_id
```